# Creation of products completely except the admin

Tags: 7, commerce

I am using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and I need to let my users to create products without the product display.

I thus adjusted the permissions, but when a user creates a product, **1/** the url is the one of the admin `admin/commerce/products/add/1` and **2/** once the created product, the user has a access denied.

My question: how to let the users to create products completely except the admin (modification of the url etc.) ?

Comment: Are you needing editing capabilities as well or just the initial creation?

Comment: thanks nvahalik, just the initial creation. The same thing as the creation of a node by a user

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a custom node bundle along with Rules. Allow the users to create the new node type. Then, when the node is being saved, use Rules (or a custom module) to take the values that were entered into the node form and carry them over to a product and save it.